# Jpa, operations with Entity and String primary key

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have this Entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter    
@Table(name="PEOPLE")
public class People implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="ALPHA_ID")
    private String alphaId;     
    
    @Column(name="FK_OTHERS")
    private Long fkOthers;

... getters and setters
}
```

and this repository

```
@Repository
public interface PeopleRepository extends CrudRepository<People, String>  {}
```

When i execute

```
Optional<People>optAss =  peopleRepository.findById(id);
```

or a native query:

```
@Query(value="select a.* from people a where a.ALPHA_ID = :id",  nativeQuery = true)
Optional<People> findByAlphaId(@Param("id") String id);
```

the results is the same -> there is NO Object.
If i print the stacktrace and the query that hibernate/jpa executes, the object is founded.

The problem is the pk String?

thanks for the help

Comment: What do you mean by printing the stacktrace? Is there any runtime error when you execute findById or the query ?

Comment: @MateiFlorescu Optional is null

Comment: @Mar-Z findById is inherited by CrudRepository library; findByAlphaId in native or non native query produce same null result

Comment: I can't see the non-args constructor in the entity class. Please define one with Lombok annotation NoArgsConstructor.

Comment: Please note that you are not using JPA Repositories. They will be auto-configured only if you extend the JpaRepository interface (not CrudRepository).